# Выподающие меню при клике

Tags: javascript

Может подскажите как реализовать всплывающие меню при клике ? или как выбрать именно тот элемент на который я нажал. у меня выскакивает только первый элемент About.

```js
var hamburger = document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger');
var menu = document.querySelector('.submenu');

var toggleMenu = function toggleMenu() {   
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
};

for(var i= 0; i< hamburger.length ; i++){
    hamburger[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  toggleMenu();

});
}
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav {
            width: 660px;
            margin: 0 auto 30px;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .topmenu>li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .topmenu>li:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            font-family: 'Lora', serif;
            transition: .5s linear;
        }

        .submenu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .nav ul {
            background: #ECDAD6;
        }

        .nav ul a {
            color: #695753;
        }

        .nav .submenu {
            display: none;
            background: #b19891;
        }

       .active{
            display: block !important;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
        <ul class="topmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li class="hamburger"><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hamburger"><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходить из вашего примера, можно сделать так

```js
var hamburger = document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger');
var menu = document.querySelector('.submenu');

var toggleMenu = function toggleMenu(_this) { 
var submenu = _this.closest('.hamburger').find('.submenu')
$('.submenu').not(submenu).removeClass('active');
submenu.toggleClass('active');
  
};

for(var i= 0; i< hamburger.length ; i++){
    hamburger[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var _this = $(this);
  toggleMenu(_this);

});
}
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav {
            width: 660px;
            margin: 0 auto 30px;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .topmenu>li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .topmenu>li:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            font-family: 'Lora', serif;
            transition: .5s linear;
        }

        .submenu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .nav ul {
            background: #ECDAD6;
        }

        .nav ul a {
            color: #695753;
        }

        .nav .submenu {
            display: none;
            background: #b19891;
        }

       .active{
            display: block !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
        <ul class="topmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li class="hamburger"><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hamburger"><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```